# Mac crashes when using Terminal app

Tags: macos, mac, terminal, kernel-panic

I'm having trouble with my MacBook Pro. Specifically, it always crashes when I try to open the Terminal app. I get the following report:

```
Anonymous UUID:       071752AC-395C-0603-2111-894859AA762E

Thu Aug 13 13:56:29 2015

*** Panic Report ***
panic(cpu 3 caller 0xffffff802c779688): "Kernel stack memory corruption detected"@/SourceCache/xnu/xnu-2782.30.5/libkern/stack_protector.c:37
Backtrace (CPU 3), Frame : Return Address
0xffffff81369ab5c0 : 0xffffff802c32bda1 
0xffffff81369ab640 : 0xffffff802c779688 
0xffffff81369ab750 : 0x36006a05bf 
Unaligned frame
Backtrace terminated-invalid frame pointer 0x8006a015e

BSD process name corresponding to current thread: system_profiler

Mac OS version:
14E46

Kernel version:
Darwin Kernel Version 14.4.0: Thu May 28 11:35:04 PDT 2015; root:xnu-2782.30.5~1/RELEASE_X86_64
Kernel UUID: E3C26B2F-8B97-3F1D-B193-690F7E34F830
Kernel slide:     0x000000002c000000
Kernel text base: 0xffffff802c200000
__HIB  text base: 0xffffff802c100000
System model name: MacBookPro9,2 (Mac-6F01561E16C75D06)

System uptime in nanoseconds: 263055487615
last loaded kext at 128835590027: com.apple.driver.AppleUSBCDC  4.3.3b1 (addr 0xffffff7faebda000, size 20480)
loaded kexts:
com.oracle.kext.OVDCUSB 4.1.51
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBCDC    4.3.3b1
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothSerialManager    4.3.5f8
com.apple.driver.AudioAUUC  1.70
com.apple.driver.AGPM   110.19.6
com.apple.driver.ApplePlatformEnabler   2.2.0d4
com.apple.driver.X86PlatformShim    1.0.0
com.apple.filesystems.autofs    3.0
com.apple.driver.AppleOSXWatchdog   1
com.apple.driver.AppleMikeyHIDDriver    124
com.apple.driver.AppleUpstreamUserClient    3.6.1
com.apple.iokit.IOUserEthernet  1.0.1
com.apple.driver.AppleMikeyDriver   272.18.1
com.apple.driver.AppleHDAHardwareConfigDriver   272.18.1
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelHD4000Graphics   10.0.6
com.apple.Dont_Steal_Mac_OS_X   7.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleHWAccess  1
com.apple.driver.AppleHV    1
com.apple.driver.AppleHDA   272.18.1
com.apple.driver.AppleLPC   1.7.3
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelSlowAdaptiveClocking 4.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSMCPDRC   1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelFramebufferCapri 10.0.6
com.apple.driver.AppleSMCLMU    2.0.7d0
com.apple.driver.ACPI_SMC_PlatformPlugin    1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleFIVRDriver    4.1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleMuxControl    3.10.24
com.apple.driver.AppleBacklight 170.7.4
com.apple.driver.AppleMCCSControl   1.2.12
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltIP 2.0.2
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothUSBDFU   4.3.5f8
com.apple.iokit.BroadcomBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport 4.3.5f8
com.apple.driver.SMCMotionSensor    3.0.4d1
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTCButtons  240.2
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTCKeyEventDriver   240.2
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTCKeyboard 240.2
com.apple.driver.AppleIRController  327.5
com.apple.driver.CoreStorageFsck    471.30.1
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBHub    705.4.2
com.apple.driver.AppleFileSystemDriver  3.0.1
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeDataless 1.0.0d1
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeZlib 1.0.0
com.apple.BootCache 36
com.apple.iokit.SCSITaskUserClient  3.7.5
com.apple.driver.XsanFilter 404
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIBlockStorage  2.7.1
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIPassThrough   1.0.3
com.apple.driver.AirPort.Brcm4331   800.20.24
com.apple.driver.AppleSDXC  1.6.5
com.apple.iokit.AppleBCM5701Ethernet    10.1.3
com.apple.driver.AirPort.Brcm4360   930.37.3
com.apple.driver.AppleFWOHCI    5.5.2
com.apple.driver.AppleAHCIPort  3.1.2
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBEHCI   705.4.14
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBXHCI   710.4.11
com.apple.driver.AppleSmartBatteryManager   161.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIButtons   3.1
com.apple.driver.AppleRTC   2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleHPET  1.8
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBIOS    2.1
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIEC    3.1
com.apple.driver.AppleAPIC  1.7
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelCPUPowerManagementClient 218.0.0
com.apple.nke.applicationfirewall   161
com.apple.security.quarantine   3
com.apple.security.TMSafetyNet  8
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelCPUPowerManagement   218.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSerialFamily  11
com.apple.kext.triggers 1.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSurface   97.4
com.apple.driver.DspFuncLib 272.18.1
com.apple.kext.OSvKernDSPLib    1.15
com.apple.iokit.IOFireWireIP    2.2.6
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusPCI  1.0.12d1
com.apple.iokit.IOSlowAdaptiveClockingFamily    1.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IOAcceleratorFamily2    156.16
com.apple.AppleGraphicsDeviceControl    3.10.24
com.apple.driver.IOPlatformPluginLegacy 1.0.0
com.apple.driver.X86PlatformPlugin  1.0.0
com.apple.driver.IOPlatformPluginFamily 5.9.1d7
com.apple.driver.AppleGraphicsControl   3.10.24
com.apple.driver.AppleBacklightExpert   1.1.0
com.apple.iokit.IONDRVSupport   2.4.1
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusController   1.0.13d1
com.apple.driver.AppleHDAController 272.18.1
com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily    2.4.1
com.apple.iokit.IOHDAFamily 272.18.1
com.apple.iokit.IOAudioFamily   203.3
com.apple.vecLib.kext   1.2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltEDMSink    4.0.3
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPOutAdapter   4.0.6
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport   4.3.5f8
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothFamily   4.3.5f8
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBUserClient 705.4.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSMC   3.1.9
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBMultitouch 245.2
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBHIDDriver  705.4.0
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBMergeNub   705.4.0
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBComposite  705.4.9
com.apple.driver.CoreStorage    471.30.1
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIMultimediaCommandsDevice  3.7.5
com.apple.iokit.IOBDStorageFamily   1.7
com.apple.iokit.IODVDStorageFamily  1.7.1
com.apple.iokit.IOCDStorageFamily   1.7.1
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPInAdapter    4.0.6
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPAdapterFamily    4.0.6
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltPCIDownAdapter 2.0.2
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCISerialATAPI   2.6.1
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIArchitectureModelFamily   3.7.5
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltNHI    3.1.7
com.apple.iokit.IOThunderboltFamily 4.2.2
com.apple.iokit.IOEthernetAVBController 1.0.3b3
com.apple.iokit.IO80211Family   730.60
com.apple.driver.mDNSOffloadUserClient  1.0.1b8
com.apple.iokit.IONetworkingFamily  3.2
com.apple.iokit.IOFireWireFamily    4.5.7
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIFamily    2.7.5
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBFamily 720.4.4
com.apple.driver.AppleEFINVRAM  2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleEFIRuntime    2.0
com.apple.iokit.IOHIDFamily 2.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSMBusFamily   1.1
com.apple.security.sandbox  300.0
com.apple.kext.AppleMatch   1.0.0d1
com.apple.driver.AppleKeyStore  2
com.apple.driver.AppleMobileFileIntegrity   1.0.5
com.apple.driver.AppleCredentialManager 1.0
com.apple.driver.DiskImages 397
com.apple.iokit.IOStorageFamily 2.0
com.apple.iokit.IOReportFamily  31
com.apple.driver.AppleFDEKeyStore   28.30
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIPlatform  3.1
com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily 2.9
com.apple.iokit.IOACPIFamily    1.4
com.apple.kec.Libm  1
com.apple.kec.pthread   1
com.apple.kec.corecrypto    1.0
```

I have tried to open with another account, but I get the same result. I've also tried to open in safe mode by holding cmd+5 on restart. It can be opened fine from there. I thought the issue might have been that the software needed updating but that wasn't the case. That being said, it took 4 attempts for me to be able to update the software, it kept crashing on me then. This has only been an issue when trying to open the terminal i.e. it doesn't happen with any other app. Also, I haven't downloaded any other apps since this started so I'm confused about what's happening. The terminal is one of the most important features I use, thus need this fixing.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Have you already tried to reapply the [10.10.4 Combo update](https://support.apple.com/downloads/DL1820/en_US/osxupdcombo10.10.4.dmg)?

Comment: currently running OS X Yosemite 10.10.4

Comment: I've just ran the mac with a new user and the terminal works fine from there. What's going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Things to try...

- Clear Terminal's saved state...
  `~/Library/Saved Application State/com.apple.Terminal.savedState` Delete the entire `com.apple.Terminal.savedState` folder.
- Fix permissions, check & if necessary repair disk, using Disk Utility
- ***re-apply*** 10.10.4 using the [10.10.4 combo update](https://support.apple.com/kb/DL1820), not the delta from App Store - as @klanomath already mentioned.
- Reset Home folder permissions & ACLs using [OnyX](http://www.titanium.free.fr/onyx.html)  - Maintenance tab/permissions, tick the box at the top then Execute.

Comment: +1 It worked. I would upvote, but not enough points yet. I tried all of the above and the one that fixed it was repair disk using disk utility. Is it bad that I've had to do this considering I only bought the mac 4 months ago. Surely that shouldn't happen this early on, should it?

Comment: I wouldn't let any one-off occurrence bother you too much. A single error could have been caused in many ways, few of them terminal. Just make sure you always have Time Machine backups & check the drives periodically, as you would with any machine. An ounce of prevention is worth a pound of cure ;)

Comment: here you go (+), since the OP could not and it is a good answer